# Symfony2 inject a service into a controller/class

Tags: php, symfony

I am working one a `simfony2` project and trying to inject `ConteinerBuilder` into one of my classes so I can use the `getParameter()` function to retrive info from p`arameters.yml` file.

My class set up:

```
namespace NewsInfrastructure\Sitemap;

use NewsInfrastructure\DatabaseRepository;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container;

class DbSitemapReadRepository extends DatabaseRepository
{

 protected $container;

 /**
     * @Route(service="parameters.container")
     * @param Container $Container
     */
public function __construct(Container $Container)
    {
        $this->container = $Container;
    }

 public function getRootURL()
    {

      $this->container->getParameter('sitemap_root_url');
    }
}
```

My serviices.xml file set up:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">

<service id="parameters.container"
         class="NewsInfrastructure\Sitemap\DbSitemapReadRepository">
    <argument type="service" id="service_container" />
</service>
```

Symfony 2 Error Message:

```
The service "parameters.container" has a dependency on e non-existing service "container"
```

I have many other services declared in this file they all work fine but not this one....does anyone see what I am doing wrong..?

OK after a suggestion to change service id from `"container"` to `"service_conteiner"` the above error message has dissapired but new one appears

New error message.

```
"Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to NewsInfrastucture\Sitemap\MyController::__construct() must be an instance of \Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ConteinerBuilder, Instance of Doctrine\DBAL\Connection given"
```

Comment: Why not inject the parameter instead ? Otherwise this is "service_container" and not "container" for the service id.

Comment: Why would it be "service_conteiner"....? well this works sort of...now I get a different error message will add it in my question now...

Comment: Can you update your services.xml too

Comment: just did @ChristopheWillemsen

Comment: The container you want is not the ContainerBuilder but Container, use ContainerInterface in your controller. Second, your service's class is wrong, you should point to your controller class

Comment: I did my changes still the the same error 2nd error

Comment: you did not changed your service class to the name of your controller's class

Comment: @ChristopheWillemsen Ok thx I belief I did now....

Comment: still the same error ?

Answer (score 1):

As Christophe says, you are better off injectiong the patameter you required.
Something like;

service.xml

```
<!-- app/config/config.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services
        http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd"
>
    <services>
        <parameters>
        <parameter key="sitemap_root_url">foo</parameter>
    </parameters>

    <services>
        <service id="DbSitemapReadRepository" class="Acme\HelloBundle\NewsInfrastructure\Sitemap\DbSitemapReadRepository">
            <argument>%sitemap_root_url%</argument>
        </service>
    </services>
    </services>
</container>
```

Class;

```
namespace NewsInfrastructure\Sitemap;

use NewsInfrastructure\DatabaseRepository;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

class DbSitemapReadRepository extends DatabaseRepository
{

 protected $siteMapUrl;

   /**
     * @param ContainerBuilder $ContainerBuilder
     */
    public function __construct($sitemap_root_url)
    {
        $this->siteMapUrl = $sitemap_root_url;
    }

}
```

Comment: plus one ,And you can remove the use statement for ContainerBuilder. Also if he really wants to inject the container, it should use ContainerInterface instead, the container builder is, as it says, for building the container and return a Container instance.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion I would be more then happy to use either as long as they work, besides my xml file containing all the declared services does not like me using the <parameters> tag it hihglight them and the whole xml file breakes

Answer (score 0):

As I said before: INJECT THE PARAMETERS, otherwise

From my comments :

```
-- app/config/config.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services
        http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd"
>

    <services>
        <service id="parameters.container" class="NewsInfrastructure\Sitemap\DbSitemapReadRepository">
            <argument type="service" name="service_container"/>
        </service>
    </services>
</container>
```

x

```
namespace NewsInfrastructure\Sitemap;

use NewsInfrastructure\DatabaseRepository;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class DbSitemapReadRepository extends DatabaseRepository
{

 protected $siteMapUrl;

   /**
     * @Route(service="parameters.container")
     * @param ContainerInterface $container
     */
    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->siteMapUrl = $container->getParameter('sitemap_url');
    }

}
```

Comment: All gd but my xml file ssays: `Element parameters: not allowed here`